# error viewing chatter group

Tags: chatter

when viewing some chatter groups, we get the following error on the screen

```
get(editable) failed on instance of core.chatter.groups.html.GroupDescriptionRenderer$GroupDescriptionModel 
The problematic instruction: ---------- ==> macro profilesection [on line 1, column 1 in */profile-section-macro.ftl] 
in user-directive profilesection [on line 3, column 1 in groupdescription.ftl] 
in include _template [on line 39, column 5 in builtin-macros.ftl] 
in user-directive composite [on line 63, column 17 in groupprofilepage.ftl]
---------- Java backtrace for programmers: ---------- 
freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: get(editable) failed on instance of core.chatter.groups.html.GroupDescriptionRenderer$GroupDescriptionModel 
at freemarker.ext.beans.BeanModel.get(BeanModel.java:224) 
at freemarker.core.Dot._getAsTemplateModel(Dot.java:76) 
at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89) 
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:568)

--- snip many many more lines ---
```

This error appears randomly without any pattern. Is there a way to not display these java errors on the screen to the end users?

Comment: Where are you viewing groups? in Classic, Lightning, Chatter Desktop, something else?

Comment: Was viewing in classic, url is /ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=<group id>

Comment: Since this is core Salesforce, your best bet is to log a case with support, sadly.